# Using same load-balancer for both external and internal traffic

Tags: load-balancing

We have a load-balancer that today balances two lightly loaded nodes, and I wondered if it possible to use it for internal traffic as well (which requires today another load-balancer). This means that this load-balancer will keep balancing external HTTP traffic, but also will balance internal SQL queries between two data-bases.

Did someone use a similar setup, or such approach is totally not recommended, or even not possible?

Comment: while it is absolutely doable (it's just a matter of routing your traffic to the load balancer), it's a bad idea from a security standpoint. Your load balancer is likely to be exposed to compromission (first equipment accessible from the outside) and also become a single point of failure if all you internal and external traffic routes through it. Think twice before you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this.  You're first tier server is also a client of the second or third tier of the overall application.

You don't mention what you are using for load balancing but here's some documentation of the subject around LVS, Linux Virtual Server:

http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.lvs_clients_on_realservers.html

Comment: Hi. How stable is such configuration from your experience?

Comment: Also, is it possible to have back-end servers, accessing the front-ends in load-balanced manner (which essentially is my question)?

Comment: It was a bit involved to setup in that we had to create a new VLAN and give the machines IP addresses to distinguish them from the rest of our network.  For backend servers to access front-ends in a load-balanced manner you'd probably need to create a new network for the backend servers to act as clients that do not arrive to your network via the internet.